# What to pass for the vmap argument of CloneFunction in llvm?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying to clone the exact copy of another function. I have not been able to find any examples of CloneFunction usage on the internets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns at the you can just create a ValueToValueMapTy variable and pass it without initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The following code segment is enough for cloning the function called Func

ValueToValueMapTy VMap;
auto *Clone = CloneFunction(Func, VMap);

rahib bob