# In LLVM, how can I get a Value's ValuetoValueMapTy (VMap)? What its purpose?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

On the context of cloning functions, one of the used objects is the `ValueToValueMapTy &VMap` which is a `typedef` of`ValueMap<const Value *, WeakVH>`.

For example, it is used during `cloneFunctionInto(...)` in `llvm/lib/Transforms/Utils/CloneFunction.cpp`

Thus I have **questions** that will help me clarify its purpose:

1. Does every `llvm::Value` has its on VMap? Or this only belongs to Functions or Modules or what?
2. How do I get this ValueMap for a specific function?
3. Is it correct that its purpose is to hold information of `llvm::Values` of the function?

---

ps.:

I have already checked those links that may be helpful to others asking questions on Vmap, but none of them could completely answer my questions.

[What to pass for the vmap argument of CloneFunction in llvm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104085/what-to-pass-for-the-vmap-argument-of-clonefunction-in-llvm)

[Filling the LLVM CloneFunction VMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441711/filling-the-llvm-clonefunction-vmap)

[LLVM CloneFunction.cpp](http://llvm.org/doxygen/CloneFunction_8cpp_source.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Purpose of the ValueMap in CloneFunction is to record the mapping from values in the source function to values in the cloned function.

Example:

```
Function *F;
Value *V = /* some register in F */;
ValueToValueMapTy VMap;
auto *Clone = CloneFunction(F, VMap);
// V2 represents essentially the same register as V,
// except it's in Clone instead of F
Value *V2 = VMap[V];
```

Comment: So the process is: First I record and later I remap? This is why I can drop it afterwards?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. I added an example in my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Are V2 (or VMap[V]) and V bonded together? Being the same thing? Or they are two different objects in two different functons and one does not depend on the life-cycle of the other anymore?

Comment: The latter. They are independent.